# What is the cloning of the list and how to clone it?

Tags: c, list, clone

Lets just say that we have a list. How can we clone that? I have created the list where I have combined two lists i.e list1 and list2. How can I clone my combined list? I need to do this in C programming

Comment: What are your efforts so far?

Comment: what do you mean by `list`? what is your struct like?

Answer (score 1):

Get the size of your list.  Then create another buffer of that size, and use memcpy to copy the memory from the location of the list to your buffer.

Comment: It would of course only work if it is an _array_, not a _list_. Another question altogether whether the person asking even makes the difference between the two.

Comment: It would work if its a list.  It depends what you define as copying and what you define as a list. If its a linked list, and you want to copy the data, you just nest the memcopy inside the pointer traversal.  If you don't want the data, you can just memcpy the pointers.  I fail to see how it wouldn't work if its a list...

Comment: memcpy copies bytes, not members of a list. If by "list" you mean a an array of bytes that is contiguous in memory, then yes. For all other cases, no.

Comment: Members of a list are bytes in memory aren't they?  They don't even have to be contiguous: if you have pointers, you just copy the memory pointed to by each pointer.  So why wouldn't this work in every case?

Comment: Please read your original answer, then my comment, then think for longer than 3 seconds, and you will see what I mean.

Comment: I fail to see yoru point.  Idk about how fluent you are in C, but if it were me, whether its a list or an array, I could clone the shit out of it using memcpy.  Maybe you're just not as smart as me idk.

Comment: Yes, you are most probably much smarter than me. I would never be able to clone the shit out of anything, for example. I will bookmark your answer, however, I am sure it would be useful at some point during my programming carrier.

Comment: Not only am I smarter, but my english is *much probably better* as you would put it.  When you get off your carrier plane, let me know and I'll come buy you a beer with my 6 figure salary.  I know pilots don't make that much, especially on carriers. Hilarious Boris, you've made my day.

Comment: As you are apparently better than me in every way imaginable, it is an honour to have made your day. May your magnificence shine over the rest of the world as brightly as it does on Stackoverflow, and at your 6-figure salary job. You do not sound at all like a 15-year old douche.

Answer (score 0):

@Magn3s1um and Jaspreet Deol
It depends on your implementation. With memcpy you can copy memory which is allocated in a sequence(let's say an array). If your list is a structure with pointers etc you have to do it node-by-node.

//EDIT

By cloning is meant that you must create a second identical object to the first one.

```
EXAMPLE
list : apples>oranges>melons
list_clone : apples>oranges>melons
```

Comment: Clarifies better when it is left as comment for other answer by @Magn3s1um